# Trigger Google Cloud Function by change in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to use a certain Google Spreadsheet as UI for a Cloud Function.
For Example, I want the columns SQLStatement, TargetSheet and TargetCell such that my colleagues can handle a GCFunction only with their SQL skills and write the results into the Google Sheets they need.

The script is working, my problem is the trigger. The Cloud Function shall be triggered by every update of the source spreadsheet, I do not need any information to be pushed to the function.

I am doing research since a couple of days, but the more I read about Firestore, Apps Script and Cloud Function Triggers the more confused I am and the farer I get from my original problem. Hence, my question is:

*What is the easiest way to trigger a cloud function by an update of a certain Google Spreadsheet?*

Answer (score 1):

The simpler solution is to use a Google Apps Script edit or change triggers. The event object for each trigger is different.

An edit trigger will be triggered only when the change is by using the Google Sheets UI, a change trigger will be triggered when the spreadsheet is edited by using the UI or when a change like inserting a row among others is made by the user or programatically.

---

The available triggers in Google Sheets are

- Open: reserved function name `onOpen`
- Edit: reserved function name `onEdit`
- Selection Change: reserved function name `onSelectionChange`
- Change: No reserved function name
- Form Submission: No reserved function name

Simple triggers use reserved functions names. Installable triggers could call any function but you should avoid to call functions that use reserved names to prevent that the fuction be triggered twice.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events